# Error while generating table from a new environment in Ubuntu

Tags: tables, environments, longtable

I am using Latex to generate Doxygen documents. 
In my doxygen.sty file I have the following environment,which is created by default:

```
\newenvironment{DoxyParams}[2][]{%
    \tabulinesep=1mm%
    \par%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
      {\begin{longtabu} spread 0pt [l]{|X[-1,l]|X[-1,l]|}}% name + description
    {\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}%
      {\begin{longtabu} spread 0pt [l]{|X[-1,l]|X[-1,l]|X[-1,l]|}}% in/out + name + desc
      {\begin{longtabu} spread 0pt [l]{|X[-1,l]|X[-1,l]|X[-1,l]|X[-1,l]|}}% in/out + type + name + desc
    }
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\hspace{-6pt}\bfseries\fontseries{bc}\selectfont\color{darkgray} #2}\\[1ex]%
    \hline%
    \endfirsthead%
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\hspace{-6pt}\bfseries\fontseries{bc}\selectfont\color{darkgray} #2}\\[1ex]%
    \hline%
    \endhead%
}{%
    \end{longtabu}%
    \vspace{6pt}%
}
```

and the following block in main tex document:

```
\begin{DoxyParams}{Parameters}
{\em p1} & description1. \\
\hline
{\em p2} & description2. \\
\hline
{\em p3} & description3. \\
\hline
\end{DoxyParams}
```

But when generating a pdf document throws following error:

```
! Misplaced \cr.
\reserved@c ->\ifnum 0=`{}\fi \cr

l.61 \end{DoxyParams}
```

> This occurs only in Ubuntu.

Doxygen version is 1.8.11
Latex version is the last